# How to tell if some vectors can sit in the same quadrant after change of coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

In a n dimensional space, suppose I have n vectors, and any two of them have non-negative inner product. Does there exist a coordinate system, under which all vectors have non-negative entries?

In other words, if the angle between any two vectors is less or equal to 90 degrees, is there a way to choose a coordinate system, so that all vectors sit in the first quadrant.

The problem sounds obvious and easy, but I've been thinking about it for a long time and still cannot work it out. Could anyone help me on that? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Travis. But it's hard for me to show why this is a nonnegative linear combination. In other words, how to show that $\langle v_i, e_j\rangle$ is nonnegative for all $j<i$.

Comment: In addition, I notice that the order of applying G-S process is important. For example, $v_1=(1,1,0)$, $v_2=(1,0,0)$ and $v_3=(0,1,1)$. If we let $e_1=v_1$, then $e_2=v_2-\frac{\langle v_2, e_1\rangle}{|e_1|^2}e_1=(\frac12,-\frac12,0)$. In this case, $\langle v_3, e_2\rangle<0$. That means, under orthogonal basis $(e_a)$, $v_3$ has a negative entry. But if we take $v_2$ first, then $v_1$, then it works.